In Qt/C++, I am building a dual threaded sgml tokenizer that threads backwards and forwards. Why is it taking twice as long instead of half?
Backstory:

Third time building a sgml parser:


QRegularExpression - Flexible & Unreliable.




QString - Slow & Reliable.




Current WIP & Proof of Concept: QStringView + Multithreading - Fast & Clean



I've been wanting to experiment with multithreaded parsing for a long time, even thought of designing my own markup that would accomodate this. My last iteration has done much of the heavy lifting for me, and now I just want to rewrite that code and optimize performance.
Multithreading Strategy:
Assume every index can represent one token.

Store tokens by that index
Tokens can be checked for by simply checking if its index integer is present


Avoid Overhead & Doublework

Have one thread work forwards, and the other work backwards.
Forward thread: p | q :Backwards thread
Each thread simply checks if its current index has gone past the other thread's index:

void QSgmlParser::forward()
{
    while ( ++p_I < q_I ) { ... }
}
void QSgmlParser::backward()
{
    while ( --q_I > p_I ) { ... }
}

Why not divide the stringview into 8 portions and tokenize it as such?

I may try it, however I fear that the overhead for resolving false positives, or finding appropriate nodes, would negate most performance gains.
Starting in the middle of a  tag would be a nightmare
The only doublework for a Forward & Backward thread would be at most, one token.

Proof of Concept:
qtoken.h My Basic Token. Its just a string ref with a few added properties.
#ifndef QTOKEN_H
#define QTOKEN_H

#include <QStringView>

class QToken : public QStringView
{
public:
    enum Token {
        None = 0
        , Tag           // Ambiguous Tag
        , Tag_s         // Self Closing Tag
        , Tag_p         // Starting Tag
        , Tag_q         // Closing Tag
        , Name          // Attribute Name
        , Value         // Attribute value
        , Comment       // comment
        , CharacterData // CDATA
        , Instruction   // instruction
        , Content       // content
        , Declaration   //
        , Script
    };

    inline QToken( Token token, const QStringView &sv )
        : QStringView(sv), m_Token(token)
    {}
    inline bool operator==( const QToken &token ) const { return this->begin() == token.begin(); }
    
private:
    Token m_Token;
};
#endif // QTOKEN_H

qsgmlparser.h Parsing Header. Switches are given their own function and inlined for performance gain. Extra features have been pruned for sample code
#ifndef QSGMLPARSER_H
#define QSGMLPARSER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtParsing/qtoken.h>
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <QFutureWatcher>

class QSgmlParser : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QSgmlParser( const QString &sgml, QObject *parent = nullptr );

protected:
    void benchmark_multithread();
    void benchmark_forwards();
    void benchmark_backwards();

    void forward ();
    void backward();

    inline void switch_p_LT();
    inline void switch_p_LT_AZ();

    inline void switch_q_GT();
    inline void switch_q_GT_FS();

private:
    QFutureWatcher<void> m_FutureWatcher;
    const QStringView p_Sgml;
    const QStringView q_Sgml;
    int p_I; // "p" Forward
    int q_I; // "q" Backward
    int p_Position;
    int q_Position;
    QList<QToken> p_Set; // Have tried different containers
    QList<QToken> q_Set; // QSet, QMap, QList, etc
    QList<QToken> pq_Set;// Does not affect multithreading
    const int m_Length;

};

#endif // QSGMLPARSER_H

qsgmlparser.cpp I added a benchmarking macro from another file. Hopefully it builds; I just swapped out a few personal library lines to qDebug()
#include "qsgmlparser.h"

#define ct_Benchmark(EXPR, repeat){\
    QElapsedTimer et;\
    int initialTime(0);\
    int totalTime(0);\
    int repeated = repeat;\
    QList<int> times;\
    et.start();\
    EXPR;\
    initialTime = et.restart();\
    for(int ___i_=0;___i_<repeated;___i_++) {\
            EXPR;\
        }\
        totalTime = et.restart();\
    double averageTime = double(totalTime/repeated);\
    const QString expression(#EXPR);\
    const QString iterations(" Cycles: "+QString::number(repeated));\
    const QString initial   ("Initial: "+QString::number(initialTime));\
    const QString total     ("  Total: "+QString::number(totalTime));\
    const QString average   ("Average: "+QString::number(averageTime));\
    qDebug() << expression << iterations << initial << total << average;\  
}


QSgmlParser::QSgmlParser( const QString &sgml, QObject *parent )
    : QObject{parent}
    , p_Sgml(sgml)
    , q_Sgml(sgml)
    , p_I(-1)
    , q_I( sgml.length() )
    , m_Length(q_I)
{
    /* Tokenization */
    ct_Benchmark( this->benchmark_forwards();, 1000 );
    ct_Benchmark( this->benchmark_backwards();, 1000 );
    ct_Benchmark( this->benchmark_multithread();, 1000 );


    pq_Set << p_Set << q_Set;
    QStringList sl;
    foreach( QToken t, pq_Set ) {
        sl << t.toString();
    }
    sl.sort();


    ct_Halt(sl);

}
void QSgmlParser::benchmark_multithread()
{
    p_I = -1;
    q_I = p_Sgml.length();
    p_Set.clear();
    q_Set.clear();

    QtConcurrent::run( &QSgmlParser::forward , this );
    m_FutureWatcher.setFuture( QtConcurrent::run( &QSgmlParser::backward, this ) );
    QEventLoop wait;
    connect( &m_FutureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, &wait, &QEventLoop::quit );
    wait.exec();

}
void QSgmlParser::benchmark_forwards()
{
    p_I = -1;
    q_I = p_Sgml.length();
    p_Set.clear();
    q_Set.clear();
    this->forward();
}
void QSgmlParser::benchmark_backwards()
{
    p_I = -1;
    q_I = p_Sgml.length();
    p_Set.clear();
    q_Set.clear();
    this->backward();
}

void QSgmlParser::forward()
{
    while ( ++p_I < q_I ) {
        switch ( p_Sgml[p_I].unicode() ) {
        case '<':
            this->switch_p_LT();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
void QSgmlParser::backward()
{
    while ( --q_I > p_I ) {
        switch ( q_Sgml[q_I].unicode() ) {
        case '>':
            this->switch_q_GT();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}


#define p_ADD( TOKEN, STRING_VIEW )\
p_Set << QToken( TOKEN, STRING_VIEW )

#define q_ADD( TOKEN, STRING_VIEW )\
q_Set << QToken( TOKEN, STRING_VIEW )

#define Double_Quotes '"': case U'”'
#define IS_SINGLE_OR_DOUBLE(SGML,ITERATOR)\
        if ( isSingle ) {\
            if ( SGML[ITERATOR] == QChar('\'') ) {\
                isSingle = false;\
            }\
            continue;\
        }\
        if ( isDouble ) {\
            if ( SGML[ITERATOR] == QChar('"') ) {\
                isDouble = false;\
            }\
            continue;\
        }



void QSgmlParser::switch_p_LT()
{
    p_Position = p_I;
    switch ( p_Sgml[++p_I].unicode() ) {
    default:
        this->switch_p_LT_AZ();
        return;
    }

}
void QSgmlParser::switch_p_LT_AZ()
{
    bool isSingle(false);
    bool isDouble(false);
    while ( ++p_I < m_Length ) {
        IS_SINGLE_OR_DOUBLE(p_Sgml,p_I)
        switch ( p_Sgml[p_I].unicode() ) {
        case '\'':
            isSingle = true;
            continue;
        case '"':
            isDouble = true;
            continue;
        case '>':
            p_ADD( QToken::Tag_s, p_Sgml.sliced( p_Position, p_I - p_Position + 1 ) );
            return;
        }
    }
}

void QSgmlParser::switch_q_GT()
{
    q_Position = q_I;
    switch ( q_Sgml[q_I].unicode() ) {
    default:
        this->switch_q_GT_FS();
        return;
    }
}
void QSgmlParser::switch_q_GT_FS()
{
    bool isSingle(false);
    bool isDouble(false);
    while ( --q_I >= 0 ) {
        IS_SINGLE_OR_DOUBLE(q_Sgml,q_I)
        switch ( q_Sgml[q_I].unicode() ) {
        case '\'':
            isSingle = true;
            continue;
        case '"':
            isDouble = true;
            continue;
        case '<':
            q_ADD( QToken::Tag_s, q_Sgml.sliced( q_I, q_Position - q_I + 1 ) );
            return;
        }
    }
}

Sample sgml
<foo0001/>
<foo0001/>
<foo0001/>
<foo0002/>
<foo0002/>
<foo0002/>
...
<foo0998/>
<foo0999/>
<foo0999/>
<foo0999/>
<foo1000/>
<foo1000/>
<foo1000/>

Results



Build
Forward
Backward
Multithreading




Release
778
766
1578


Debug
12484
12247
14127



IE under both builds, the multithreading is taking longer. I am using GCC.
Given the overhead, I feel like I should be able to get a score of at least 500 on the multithreading.
This persists regardless of how large my sample size becomes, which makes me rule out the threading overhead. My goal is to at least be able to get a modest gain but as of now, I feel like there is a large oversight that I simply do not understand, and I don't think its the overhead. And before I actually expend the effort on flushing out the parser, I need to see if I can actually gain an advantage for the rudimentary parsing first.
I tried asking around but have not gotten much feedback. AI did suggest something about CPU cache, but I couldnt really follow what it was trying to say, and suspected it might just be giving me some answer that is not particularly relevant.
Can anyone help me get to the bottom of why this rudimentary parsing is taking twice as long instead of half as long?
What am I overlooking?
Thanks.

You have a lot of race conditions due to lack of atomics

Note that the QEventLoop::exec function will block and wait for its exit function to be called. So whatever thread called QSgmlParser::benchmark_multithread() will be put on hold until the new thread is finished. That makes your code serial, not parallel.

On a totally different note, I'm sure that Qt says that the Q and q prefixes for all its functions and classes is because it's in the Qt library, to avoid name-clashes with other classes. I doubt you're supposed to use it for your own code.

@AhmedAEK I can't see a single race condition other than perhaps the thread management. Everything else is decoupled. forward() and backward() can run completely independantly. What am I missing here that you see?

@Anon Re. "I can't see a single race condition": both QSgmlParser::forward and QSgmlParser::backward access p_I and q_I without any synchronization.

Also on a different note, I think you do too much in your QSgmlParser constructor. It should initialize the object to a known state, but not really much else. It should (IMO) not do any kind of processing or business logic.

Your variables are all close together and on the same cache line so you also have False Sharing, but it is not the only slowdown, i suspect you also have a hidden lock somewhere slowing you down even more, you might want to run this code inside a profiler.

As an aside, your QSgmlParser::benchmark_multithread implementation never waits for QSgmlParser::forward to finish (unless that's handled elsewhere).  That being the case, your bench-marking code is potentially starting calls to QSgmlParser::forward while one or more previous calls are still running.

@G.M. I assumed that given it is just a simple integer in which its current value really doesnt matter, it wouldnt need any synchronization. Is the program slowing itself down then? I'm a bit green when it comes to atomic operations.

@AhmedAEK I tried using atomic integers and that made it nearly 20× slower. I did try splitting the cache line, and it looks like it improved multithreading performance about 10%, which is interesting, but I am still far behind. If I make only one of the integers volatile, that increases performance on the threaded function, but multithreading is still twice as slow.

The atomic removes the race condition so the code works correctly (as opposed to having a bug or a heisenbug). As i have said before about performance, run it through a profiler or provide a complete example so other people can profile it.

@AhmedAEK I asked chatGTP, and it suggested that I am right to be skeptical in this case for the needs of "atomic" integers. It stated that with such simple operations, and given the fact that my algorythm can easily tolerate a few extra cycles, and that there are no intermediary values of the integer ( Or wild values ), that what you are suggesting is simply incorrect. I asked in IRC to verify and was warned about different compilers and undefined behaviour. Addressing this with chatGTP though, it reassured me that bugs here are more or less impossible given the design.

@Anon you can get away with relaxed order loads and stores on those atomics which will remove most of the atmonic performance degradation, a volatile is not a replacement for an atomic if you want code that still works on your coworkers's pc and doesn't malfunction every full moon or every compiler update (race conditions are UB), as for chatgpt you should ask it for medical prescriptions and legal advices and see where that gets you.

Any compiler can optimize away access to p_I and q_I because they never change according to the c++ memory model, it can just read them before the loop and store them in registers and update them at the end of the function, volatile means the compiler is not allowed to optimize it but your CPU still can and it can only read those from L1 caches of each thread because the cpu is never told that it needs other threads to see the updated value, this is where atomic comes in, different platforms and different architectures can have different behavior, that's why you need the atomic.

If your algorithm can indeed tolerate a few overlapping iterations then you don't need to synchronize both threads each and every iteration, you can chunk the input into chunks of say 50 characters and only check for overlap every 50 characters, this will improve performance without being UB ... a lot of profilers would've told you how much time you spend synchronizing vs doing the actual work so you can optimize accordingly.
